# Removed Homebrew now the jpeg and png images don't display

Tags: install

Recently I removed the Homebrew completely on my OS X 10.7.4 (because the only reason I was using it was the OpenSSL package and I installed it from scratch into `/usr/local`and it worked perfectly so there was no need to keep a large `/usr/local/Cellar` folder)

Then when I started Emacs-25.2.1 (as a precompiled app in `/Applications/Emacs-25.2.app`) it gave

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Emacs-25.2.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
  Reason: image not found
```

and the Emacs windows didn't come up.

I've noticed one of the dependencies of Emacs `/usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.1.dylib` was symlinking to `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7/libd/libMagickCore-6.Q16.1.dylib` So I've installed `ImageMagick-7.0.8-60` from scratch and rearranged the symlink into this new one and repeated the same for the other Dyld Error causing `MagickCore` and finally Emacs started to come up and work fine but it wasn't displaying the jpg and png images.

I've checked the libjpeg dependency path and it is `/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.0.0)` But the `libjpeg.8.dylib` was already available at `/usr/local/lib` so I've installed the libjpeg-8c, 8d, 9c and retried but it didn't display any jpeg images. I guess I got stuck at this point.

How to fix this problem? Thanks.

Attachment:

```
$ otool -L /Applications/Emacs-25.2.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
/Applications/Emacs-25.2.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1138.47.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.3.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libncurses.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libgnutls.30.dylib (compatibility version 37.0.0, current version 37.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 635.21.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 41.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 833.25.0)
```

Comment: Where did you get that Emacs from?

Comment: It was from emacsformacosx.com i.e. plain and pure build for OS X.

Comment: @nega  I've attached an otool output showing all dependencies of Emacs-25.2.

Comment: Did you overwrite that Emacs with another one?  A fresh download of https://emacsformacosx.com/emacs-builds/Emacs-25.2-universal.dmg has `/Applications/Emacs-25.2.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` as a Ruby script, and none of the four binaries are dynamically linked to `libjpeg`. Try moving your Emacs aside, and downloading a fresh copy.

Comment: Coincidentally,  today afternoon I've done exactly that downloaded Emacs-25.2-universal.dmg and tried it. But when I clicked on it it didn't even start, the Emacs icon on the dock bounced for tens of seconds and Emacs didn't ever start up. Then I have tried compiling Emacs-25.2 from sources up with `/configure --prefix=/usr/local/emacs-25.2 --with-ns` but it said `checking AppKit/AppKit.h presence... yes checking AppKit/AppKit.h usability... no`  then stoped with `configure: error: (AppKit/AppKit.h etc) that
are required for a Nextstep build are missing or cannot be compiled.`

Comment: Meanwhile, here is a screenshot of the Emacs-25.2, after having start up but without displaying the splash image [emacs-25.2-OSX-10.7.4](https://i.ibb.co/QDHBZPb/Bildschirmfoto-2019-08-19-um-18-09-39.png)

Comment: Installing Emacs-25.2 from emacsforosx.com doesn't install any icons to Launchpad or the desktop. That icon is probably from your previous, broken install. Open your fresh Emacs via Finder, or via Terminal.app with `open -a Emacs --args -q`, `open /Applications/Emacs.app --args -q` or `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -q`. Of course, you can also create your own icon.

Comment: I've tried the first command `open -a Emacs --args -q`and it gave a `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application with error -10810` after I investigated the cause of it I've come across a post saying that OS X cannot execute the .app. So I've browsed into the `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents` and selected the `MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_7` manually and finally it opened and with the splash image. If you post an answer with comments on why this trouble might have happened, let me select it as the answer.

Comment: Is `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` a ruby script? and what happens when you run it directly?

Comment: Yes it's a Ruby script, when I run it it says `/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` Hm then I guess, after I completely removed the Homebrew, it must have removed the Ruby symlink `/usr/bin/ruby` too. Now I've re-created a Ruby symlink and Emacs.app started to open without any problems. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your Emacs app has been overwritten. If you've already removed Homebrew, remove all references to emacs from `/usr/local`. Then remove `/Applications/Emacs.app` and/or `~/Applications/Emacs.app`. Remove the icons from Launchpad and the app bar. During this process take care not to remove bits of macOS's default Emacs (version 22.1.1) from `/usr`. In your terminal, check your path with `which emacs`. The default `/usr/bin/emacs` should be the response. In your terminal check with `open`. `open -a Emacs` should fail. If not, there's an Emacs.app somewhere on you computer that macOS can still find. Get rid of it.

At this point we should be mostly clean, or clean enough. Download your preferred version of Emacs from http://emacsforosx.com. Open the `.dmg`. Drag the Emacs icon on to the Applications icon. Give it a minute to do its thing. Unmount the `.dmg` file by dragging the Emacs "drive" to the trash, or right-clicking it and selecting Eject.

At this point we have a fresh Emacs app bundle installed at `/Applications/Emacs.app`. Running `open -a Emacs` or clicking `/Applications/Emacs` in Finder should start Emacs.

If Emacs doesn't start, in your terminal run `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`. (That's what `open -a` or clicking via Finder essentially does.) In the package provided http://emacsforosx.com this is a Ruby script. If you get a "bad interpreter" error, there's a problem with your local Ruby. Fix that and things should work again. Other errors may indicate an incompatiblity between  your Emacs version and your macOS version. Address those as needed. As a last resort if one of the version specific binaries works for you, say for example `Emacs-x86_64-10_7` you can always symlink that to `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` so that Find and `open -a` will work. Again, that would be a last resort.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After doing all those checks, the problem seemed to be caused by a combination of the damaged `/Application/Emacs-25.2` and bad Ruby interpreter. Homebrew's uninstall script must have removed the Ruby interpreter causing the normally working Emacs.app not to work and I myself must have damaged the `/Application/Emacs-25.2` as I was trying in a hurry different versions of Emacs.I don't exactly remember which actions I took, I have even sent it to trash folder and taken it back again. At the end, it's good to see the fully functioning `Emacs-25.2` again :)